# Deep copy std::string::c_str() to char *

Tags: c++, string

Currently I have a complex function that myself and our team are not wanting to refactor to utilize std::string and it takes a char* which is modified. How would I properly make a deep-copy of string::c_str() into a char*? I am **not** looking to modify the string's internally stored char*.

```
char *cstr = string.c_str();
```

fails because c_str() is const.

Comment: Is this C++11? Copy the `std::string` and use `&stringCopy[0]`.

Comment: `strdup`, `new/strcpy`, @chris' suggestion, ... You have the choice.

Comment: sprintf(cstr,"%s", somestring.c_str())

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
const std::string::size_type size = string.size();
char *buffer = new char[size + 1];   //we need extra char for NUL
memcpy(buffer, string.c_str(), size + 1);
```

Comment: *Please, please* use a correct type for the string size, eg. `std::string::size_type` or `std::size_t`.

Comment: @syam ahh you are absolutely right :)

Comment: Don't forget to delete it. Or better still, get `std::vector<char>` to do that for you, and access the array as `v.data()` or `&v[0]`. Or even another `string`, if you don't mind borderline-undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than modify the existing function, I'd just create an overload that acts as a wrapper. Assuming the existing function is `ret_type f(char *)`, I'd write the overload something like:

```
ret_type f(std::string s) { 
    return f(&s[0]);
}
```

Note passing `s` by value instead of reference, minimizing the effort expended to get a copy of the string.

In theory, this isn't guaranteed to work (i.e., a string's buffer isn't guaranteed to be contiguous) until C++03. In reality, that guarantee was fairly easy for the committee to add primarily because nobody knew of an implementation of `std::string` that did anything else.

Likewise, it could theoretically be missing the NUL terminator. If you're concerned about that possibility you could use `return f(const_cast<char *>(s.c_str()));` instead, or add an `s.push_back('\0');` before the return:

```
ret_type f(std::string s) { 
    s.push_back('\0');
    return f(&s[0]);
}
```

Comment: I would do a `s.push_back( '\0' )` in your wrapper function, just to be sure.  And you surely meant `const_cast` in the last bit of code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oops -- yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is:

```
std::vector<char> tmp( string.begin(), string.end() );
tmp.push_back( '\0' );
function( &tmp[0] );
```

(I rather like Jerry Coffin's solution, however.)